# Como detectar la resolución de un video desde código?

Tags: android

¿Cómo obtener la resolucion de un video que he cargado con *setVideoUri*.?
Tengo varios videos con poca resolución y lo que tengo pensado hacer es si la resolución del video a reproducir es menor a 720p reducir el tamaño del *videoView* para que se visualice mejor, pero no tengo idea de como obtener la resolucion del video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource("file_path");
String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
String width = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
```

**Update**

Si al compilar la aplicación arroja IllegalArgumentException, intenta el agregar el siguiente código:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
   metaRetriever.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
else
   metaRetriever.setDataSource(link);
```

[Referencia](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794)

Comment: No sabes si es posible dar la ruta por medio de una url?, es decir, el video no se encuentra en el dispositivo, se encuentra en mi pc y de ahí lo reprodusco con setVideoUri. Intente lo que me dijiste pero me marca error. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, esta función solo funciona para videos que se encuentran en el dispositivo?

Comment: @ErickRaulMarquez La clase funciona para videos internos y externos, revisa el update a ver si te sirve. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó con el update.